# Using OpenSSL TLS with or without BIO?

Tags: ssl, openssl

I've been reading a lot about OpenSSL, specifically the TLS and DTLS APIs. Most of it makes sense, it's a pretty intuitive API once you understand it. One thing has really got me scratching my head though...

When/why would I use BIOs?

For example, [this wiki page](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Simple_TLS_Server) demonstrates setting up a barebones TLS server. There isn't even a *mention* of BIOs anywhere in the example.

Now [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20130327081616/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-openssl/index.html) Uses BIOs exclusively, not ever using the read and write functions of the SSL struct. Granted it's from 2013, but it's not the only one that uses BIOs.

To make it even more confusing [this man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_read.html) suggests that the SSL struct has an "underlying BIO" *without ever needing to set it explicitly*.

So why would I use BIOs if I can get away with using `SSL_read()` and `SSL_write()`? What are the advantages? Why do some examples use BIOs and others don't? What Is the Airspeed Velocity of an Unladen Swallow?

Comment: One use of BIO is to upgrade an existing socket to TLS.

Comment: @user207421: You can upgrade a socket to TLS without using BIO just by using `SSL_set_fd` followed by the `SSL_connect` or `SSL_accept` on an existing TCP socket.

Comment: African or European swallow?

Answer (score 4):

BIO's are always there, but they might be hidden by the simpler interface. Directly using the BIO interface is useful if you want more control - with more effort. If you just want to use TLS on a TCP socket then the simple interface is usually sufficient. If you instead want to use TLS on your own underlying transport layer or if you want have more control on how it interacts with the transport layer then you need BIO.

An example for such a use case is [this proposal](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-friel-tls-atls-02) where TLS is tunneled as JSON inside HTTPS, i.e. the TLS frames are encoded in JSON and which is then transferred using POST requests and responses. This can be achieved by handling the TLS with memory BIO's which are then encoded to and decoded from JSON.

Answer (score 1):

First, your Q is not very clear. `SSL` is (a typedef for) a C struct type, and you can't use the dot operator on a struct type in C, only an instance. Even assuming you meant 'an instance of `SSL`', as people sometimes do, in older versions (through 1.0.2) it did not have members `read` and `write`, and in 1.1.0 up it is opaque -- you don't even know what its members are.

Second, there are two different levels of BIO usage applicable to the SSL library. The SSL/TLS connection (represented by the `SSL` object, plus some related things linked to it like the session) always uses two BIOs to respectively send and receive protocol data -- including both protocol data that contains the application data you send with `SSL_write` and receive with `SSL_read`, and the SSL/TLS handshake that is handled within the library. Much as [Steffen describes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56591494/), these normally are both set to a socket-BIO that sends to and receives from the appropriate remote host process, but they can instead be set to BIOs that do something else in-between, or even instead. (This normal case is automatically created by `SSL_set_{,r,w}fd` which it should be noted on Windows actually takes a socket handle -- but not any other file handle; only on Unix are socket descriptors semi-interchangeable with file descriptors.)

Separately, the SSL/TLS connection itself can be 'wrapped' in an ssl-BIO. This allows an application to handle an SSL/TLS connection using mostly the same API calls as a plain TCP connection (using a socket-BIO) or a local file, as well as the provided 'filter' BIOs like a digest (md) BIO or a base64 encoding/decoding BIO, and any additional BIOs you add. This is the case for the IBM webpage you linked (which is for a client not a server BTW). This is similar to the Unix 'everything is (mostly) a file' philosophy, where for example the utility program `grep`, by simply calling `read` on fd 0, can search data from a file, the terminal, a pipe from another program, or (if run under inetd or similar) from a remote system using TCP (but not SSL/TLS, because that isn't in the OS). I haven't encountered many cases where it is particularly beneficial to be able to easily interchange SSL/TLS data with some other type of source/sink, but OpenSSL does provide the ability.